# Will changes to libc.conf affect the rest of my environment?

Tags: ubuntu, shared-library

I had to comment `/usr/local/lib` under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` to get a software called `qgis` up and running. If I uncomment it `qgis` fails. Will commenting out /usr/local/lib have an effect on my other executables ? This is on `Ubuntu 14.04` by the way.

Comment: How does qgis fail without the comment-out?

Comment: The likely answer is "Yes, you might break things", but details on the errors you're having and the failures you're seeing are needed first to rule out things.

Comment: @DanCornilescu - that is because I have intel compiler on my system. it is searching for libimf.so and it cannot find it for whatever reason

Comment: @DanCornilescu - I uncommented /usr/local/lib then ran ldconfig and it worked just fine.

Comment: Typically inability to locate a .so lib can be addressed by customizing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var.

Comment: @DanCornilescu - tried that. no go. The libimf.so was part of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I find it a bit weird that `removing` a dir causes a lib to be found. What does `ldconfig -p | grep libimf` say in the success case?

Comment: @DanCornilescu - That returns empty for the success case.

Comment: That means `libimf.so` is not actually mandatory, it must be picked up via some (conditional?) dependency due to from a library found in /usr/local/lib. Which *might* be addressable eventually via LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I don't know how to identify the dependency causing the issue which needs to be fullfiled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24728/discussion-between-gansub-and-dan-cornilescu).